# How to minimize Logging impact

Tags: c#, performance, logging

There's already a question about this [**issue**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684961/minimize-performance-impact-of-event-logging), but it's not telling me what I need to know: 
Let's assume I have a web application, and there's a lot of logging on every roundtrip. I don't want to open a debate about *why* there's so much logging, or how can I do less loggin operations. I want to know what possibilities I have in order to make this logging issue **performant** and **clean**.

So far, I've implemented declarative (attribute based) and imperative logging, which seems to be a cool and clean way of doing it... now, **what can I do about performance**, assuming I can expect those logs to take more time than expected. **Is it ok to open a thread and leave that work to it?**

Comment: Not that this is a specific enough answer but I know that if you do logging you're supposed to log out across the network to a drive that your web application is not on.  Because then the performance will not be hindered by the log being written to the same drive the webapp is running on.

Comment: @leeand00 That's nonsense.

Comment: You could use something like Gurock Smartinspect which allows for logging across pipes, tcp as well as file logging. It also allows for async logging and is easy to use. http://www.gurock.com/smartinspect/

Comment: Is your logging "fire and forget", meaning if the log entry fails, does the user need to be notified, any processing need to be rolled back and tried again, etc.?

Comment: @mbeckish yes, user doesn't need to be aware about logging errors.

Comment: @Hans Passant, measuring was done, logging takes longer than expected. I can't change logging code.

Comment: @lcidis, I can't change logging code, thanks for the hint, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the code below to Log. It is a singleton that accepts Logging and puts every message into a concurrentqueue. Every two seconds it writes all that has come in to the disk. Your app  is now only delayed by the time it takes to put every message in the list. It's my own code, feel free to use it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FastLibrary
{
    public enum Severity : byte
    {
        Info = 0,
        Error = 1,
        Debug = 2
    }

    public class Log
    {
        private struct LogMsg
        {
            public DateTime ReportedOn;
            public string Message;
            public Severity Seriousness;
        }

        // Nice and Threadsafe Singleton Instance
        private static Log _instance;

        public static Log File
        {
            get { return _instance; }
        }

        static Log()
        {
            _instance = new Log();
            _instance.Message("Started");
            _instance.Start("");
        }

         ~Log()
        {
            Exit();
        }

        public static void Exit()
        {
            if (_instance != null)
            {
                _instance.Message("Stopped");
                _instance.Stop();
                _instance = null;
            }
        }

        private ConcurrentQueue<LogMsg> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<LogMsg>();
        private Thread _thread;
        private string _logFileName;
        private volatile bool _isRunning;

        public void Message(string msg)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(new LogMsg { ReportedOn = DateTime.Now, Message = msg, Seriousness = Severity.Info });
        }

        public void Message(DateTime time, string msg)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(new LogMsg { ReportedOn = time, Message = msg, Seriousness = Severity.Info });
        }

        public void Message(Severity seriousness, string msg)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(new LogMsg { ReportedOn = DateTime.Now, Message = msg, Seriousness = seriousness });
        }

        public void Message(DateTime time, Severity seriousness, string msg)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(new LogMsg { ReportedOn = time, Message = msg, Seriousness = seriousness });
        }

        private void Start(string fileName = "", bool oneLogPerProcess = false)
        {
            _isRunning = true;
            // Unique FileName with date in it. And ProcessId so the same process running twice will log to different files
            string lp = oneLogPerProcess ? "_" + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id : "";
            _logFileName = fileName == ""
                               ? DateTime.Now.Year.ToString("0000") + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("00") +
                                 DateTime.Now.Day.ToString("00") + lp + "_" +
                                 System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Application.ExecutablePath) + ".log"
                               : fileName;
            _thread = new Thread(LogProcessor);
            _thread.IsBackground = true;
            _thread.Start();
        }

        public void Flush()
        {
            EmptyQueue();
        }

        private void EmptyQueue()
        {
            while (_queue.Any())
            {
                var strList = new List<string>();
                //
                try
                {
                    // Block concurrent writing to file due to flush commands from other context
                    lock (_queue)
                    {
                        LogMsg l;
                        while (_queue.TryDequeue(out l)) strList.Add(l.ReportedOn.ToLongTimeString() + "|" + l.Seriousness + "|" + l.Message);
                        if (strList.Count > 0)
                        {
                            System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(_logFileName, strList);
                            strList.Clear();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    //ignore errors on errorlogging ;-)
                }
            }
        }

        public void LogProcessor()
        {
            while (_isRunning)
            {
                EmptyQueue();
                // Sleep while running so we write in efficient blocks
                if (_isRunning) Thread.Sleep(2000);
                else break;
            }
        }

        private void Stop()
        {
            // This is never called in the singleton.
            // But we made it a background thread so all will be killed anyway
            _isRunning = false;
            if (_thread != null)
            {
                _thread.Join(5000);
                _thread.Abort();
                _thread = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll use an extension method to "override" logging and use that concurrent queue technique, I'll let you know if it gets better times, but this is what I was looking for, thanks for the code example.

Answer (score 3):

Things I would consider:

- Use an efficient file format to minimise the quantity of data to be written (e.g. XML and text formats are easy to read but usually terribly inefficient - the same information can be stored in a binary format in a much smaller space). But don't spend lots of CPU time trying to pack data "optimally". Just go for a simple format that is compact but fast to write.
- Test use of compression on the logs. This may not be the case with a fast SSD but in most I/O situations the overhead of compressing data is less than the I/O overhead, so compression gives a net gain (although it is a compromise - raising CPU usage to lower I/O usage).
- Only log useful information. No matter how important you think everything is, it's likely you can find something to cut out.
- Eliminate repeated data. e.g. Are you logging a client's IP address or domain name repeatedly? Can these be reported once for a session and then not repeated? Or can you store them in a map file and use a compact index value whenever you need to reference them? etc
- Test whether buffering the logged data in RAM helps improve performance (e.g. writing a thousand 20 byte log records will mean 1,000 function calls and could cause a lot of disk seeking and other write overheads, while writing a single 20,000 byte block in one burst means only one function call and could give significant performance increase and maximise the burst rate you get out to disk). Often writing blocks in sizes like (4k, 16k, 32, 64k) of data works well as it tends to fit the disk and I/O architecture (but check your specific architecture for clues about what sizes might improve efficiency). The down side of a RAM buffer is that if there is a power outage you will lose more data. So you may have to balance performance against robustness.
- (Especially if you are buffering...) Dump the information to an in-memory data structure and pass it to another thread to stream it out to disk. This will help stop your primary thread being held up by log I/O. Take care with threads though - for example, you may have to consider how you will deal with times when you are creating data faster than it can be logged for short bursts - do you need to implement a queue, etc?
- Are you logging multiple streams? Can these be multiplexed into a single log to possibly reduce disk seeking and the number of open files?
- Is there a hardware solution that will give a large bang for your buck? e.g. Have you used SSD or RAID disks? Will dumping the data to a different server help or hinder? It may not always make much sense to spend $10,000 of developer time making something perform better if you can spend $500 to simply upgrade the disk.

Comment: One thing to beware of if using a RAM buffer in a time sensitive operation is that at some point the buffer has to flush to disk, and this can be an expensive operation.  You may consider flushing the buffer right before starting a time sensitive operation to avoid the buffer becoming full and being forced to flush during the operation.

Comment: There are log files and windows event log behind the logging calls. I'm interested on opening threads and queueing calls. Do you think it can be a good solution? I basically want to take this process away from the principal thread. Do you have a link o something about this "log queue" stuf?

Comment: @Denise: Yes, it's best to avoid both tiny and large buffers as both extremes can cause performance issues. 4k-64k are usually good sizes to try.

Comment: @Chuck: It sounds like dropping the logging onto another thread may help relieve the load on your primary thread. Perhaps you could add the data to a [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) from that thread and have your log thread read it out the other end for writing to the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the logger is debug enabled before calling logger.debug, this means your code does not have to evaluate the message string when debug is turned off.

```
if (_logger.IsDebugEnabled) _logger.Debug($"slow old string {this.foo} {this.bar}");
```